# Clicking play on HTML5 video controls doesn't get rid of my Play button overlay

Tags: javascript, html, video

My HTML5 video player has a bug. I thought I could fix it easily but it is not looking to be that easy. When you click the overlay the video plays and the overlay disappears. But I noticed at the start of the video clicking play (not my overlay) on HTML5 video controls doesn't get rid of my play button overlay

**HTML**

```
<div class="video-wrapper">
  <video class="video" id="bVideo" loop controls>
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
  <div id="playButton" class="playButton" onclick="playPause()"></div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
var bunnyVideo = document.getElementById("bVideo");

function playPause() {
  var el = document.getElementById("playButton");
  if (bunnyVideo.paused) {
    bunnyVideo.play();
    el.className ="";
  } else {
    bunnyVideo.pause();
    el.className = "playButton";
  }
}

bunnyVideo.addEventListener("click", playPause, false);
```

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wm3ot3ko/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell if user clicked video element or one of the video controls?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22920691/how-to-tell-if-user-clicked-video-element-or-one-of-the-video-controls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to also track the play/pause events on the video itself to change the state of your overlay

not the most elegant, but this sets the overlay to just trigger play/pause and handles hiding/showing the button on a separate event that gets triggered based on the video behavior

```
var el = document.getElementById("playButton");
function playPause() {
  if (bunnyVideo.paused) {
    bunnyVideo.play();
  } else {
    bunnyVideo.pause();
  }
}
function playPause2() {
  if (!bunnyVideo.paused) {
    el.className ="";
  } else {
    el.className = "playButton";
  }
}

bunnyVideo.addEventListener("click", playPause, false);
bunnyVideo.addEventListener("play", playPause2, false);
bunnyVideo.addEventListener("pause", playPause2, false);
```

Comment: :) you probably want to tidy up the function names, but should be pretty reliable. I wish the html5 video object exposed the controls individually, both to tie events to but also to control styling...

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css file

```
#playButton {display: none; }
#playButton.playButton {display: inline; }
```

Comment: i added that and It didn't fix anything

Comment: If you change the div to `<div id="playButton"  onclick="playPause()"></div>` does that fix it?  I am not quite sure what you want.

Comment: if you notice in the fiddle, if you press the small play button in the controls (lower left), the overlay stays. I want it gone

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the most elegant/professional solution but it does the job. I just attached an event listener to the video itself on the play/pause events and toggled the 'playButton' class on/off, which is the class that determines whether that overlay is visible.  I also removed those lines from your playPause function since the .onplay event listener will take care of it.

```
var bunnyVideo = document.getElementById("bVideo");
var el = document.getElementById("playButton");

function playPause() {

  if (bunnyVideo.paused) {
    bunnyVideo.play();
  } else {

    bunnyVideo.pause();
  }
}

bunnyVideo.addEventListener("click", playPause, false);

bunnyVideo.onplay = function() {
    el.className ="";
};

bunnyVideo.onpause = function() {
    el.className ="playButton";
};
```